# Is there any way to condense a for-else loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-else

I have made a piece of code that spits out prime numbers up to the 10001st number. It currently takes up 4 lines of code, and was wondering if I could condense it further? Here it is;

```
for i in range(3,104744,2):
    for x in range(3,int(i/2),2):
        if i % x == 0 and i != x: break
    else: print(i)
```

I **am** aware that condensing code too much is usually not a good thing, but was wondering if it was possible.

Thanks.

Comment: That code is never going to produce `2`, which is a prime number.

Comment: I tried applying DeMorgan's law to your `if` statement (`i % x == 0` is functionally `not i % x` so you have two `not`s which can be factored out and the `and` changed to `or`...) resulting in `if not (i % x or i == x): break`... but that's the same number of characters!

Comment: You could try putting it all into a list comprehension.

Comment: I guess `for p in (i for i in range(...) if all(i % x for x in range(...))` but meh

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to get a one-liner solution:

```
>>> [p for p in range(2, 100) if not any (p % d == 0 for d in range(2, int(p**0.5) + 1))]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

It uses the fact that a divisor cannot be larger than the square root of the number it divies.

It seems to work fine:

```
>>> len([p for p in range(2, 104744) if not any (p % d == 0 for d in range(2,int(p**0.5)+1))])
10001
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension

```
>>> r=range(2,100)
>>> [p for p in r if [p%d for d in r].count(0)<2]
```

[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
for i in range(3,100,2):
    if all( i%x for x in range(3, i//2, 2) ):
        print(i)
```

Comment: @eyllanesc, there is no such requirement question and as far as I can see - my code is shorter than original one